# I want my UITableView to be responsive to Firebase

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have `UITableViewCells` with Like/Unlike label for a social networking app. The label have `UITapGestureRecognizer` methods to perform actions for Like and Unlike feature. Though it performs well in the application. The application is not notified of any changes in the Firebase database. Here’s a snippet of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
if (cell.likeLabel.text == "Like") {
      let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(FeedTableViewController.likeTapped))
      cell.likeLabel.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
}
else if (cell.likeLabel.text == "Unlike") {
      let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(FeedTableViewController.unlikeTapped))
      cell.likeLabel.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
}
```

I want it to be responsive to increment and decrement the number of likes in the database based on likes and unlikes. When the application loads the JSON from the database, it has a particular number of likes to show (suppose 5), but once it’s loaded, and I change the number in the database (to maybe 10), when the like label is tapped, it’d increment to 6 and decrement to 5 when unliked, when it should instead increment to 11 and decrement to 9. Here’s a snippet of one of the `UITabGestureRecognizer` methods:

```
func likeTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    // Get references
    guard let label = sender.view as? UILabel else { print("Error not a label"); return }
    let position = sender.locationInView(self.tableView)
    guard let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(position) else { print("Error label not in tableView"); return }

    // Notify TableView of pending updates
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    defer { self.tableView.endUpdates() }

    // Reference to numberOfLikes
    var numberOfLikes = self.tableViewModel[indexPath.row].numberOfLikes

    numberOfLikes += 1
    self.tableViewModel[indexPath.row].numberOfLikes = numberOfLikes

    // Update Firebase
}
```

Comment: The problem is not your code for responding to taps. You need to show the code you have that listens to the database and updates `numberOfLikes`. I'm guessing it's not there or isn't working.

Comment: @drekka Here’s the listener methods of Firebase that I use: `refNewsFeed.child(currentUserID!).queryOrderedByChild("timestamp_utc").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in`